# Where in mediawiki "Page deleted" flag located

Tags: mediawiki

I need to build SQL query, but cannot find column which determines if page was deleted. I see archive table, but can't bind, because data is different

Comment: See [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table#Deleting_pages_with_their_relationships_in_text_and_revision_tables).

Comment: No, psysical delete is not my case

Comment: Actually found source. To understand if page was deleted, you might look in logging table. Action and Type columns are the keys [there is delete text]